# Verify Google ID Token with Node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, swift

I have an iOS app that's sending a google id to a backend server for validation.

I'm following the Google guidelines: https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/backend-auth

I'm quite new to Node js and I can't figure out why the callback function never gets executed (i.e., the promise doesn't resolve nor reject):

```
const verifyToken = new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
    console.log("promise function")
    client.verifyIdToken({
        idToken: token,
        audience: process.env.CLIENT_ID, 
        function (e, login){
            console.log(e)
           if (login) {
               var payload = login.getPayload();
               var googleId = payload['sub'];
               resolve(googleId);
            } else {
            reject("invalid token");
           }
        }
    });
});
verifyToken.then((token) => {
    console.log("RESOLVED");
    jwt.sign({id: googleId}, 'secret key', { algorithm: 'RS256' }, (err, token) => {
        console.log("sending data back");
        res.send(token);
    });
});
verifyToken.catch((message) => {
    console.log("REJECTED");
    res.send(message);
});
```

Comment: can you please explain how did you get `token` for verifyIdToken function? because I can't find any method to get token for this.....

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The best way to verify Google ID token is to use ***google-auth-library*** from ***npm*** below is a sample snippet for validating the tokenId sent from client to the server, hope it helps.

```
const {GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID, JWT_SECRET } = process.env;

app.post('/api/v1/auth/google', async ({ body: { tokenId } }, res) => {

  const client = new OAuth2Client(GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID);

  const ticket = await client.verifyIdToken({
    idToken: tokenId,
    audience: GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID,
  });

  const response = ticket.getPayload();

  if (response.iss !== 'accounts.google.com' && response.aud !== GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID)
    return res.status(400).json({ status: 'error', error: 'Bad Request' });

  const user = {
    email: response.email,
    image: response.picture,
    social_id: response.sub,
    first_name: response.given_name,
    last_name: response.family_name,
  };

  let result = await User.findOne({
    where: { [Op.or]: [{ email: user.email }, { social_id: user.social_id }] },
  });

  if (!result) result = await User.create(user);

  const token = await jwt.sign({ id: result.dataValues.id }, JWT_SECRET, { expiresIn: '1hr' });
  const data = { token, ...result.dataValues};

  res.status(200).json({ status: 'success', data });

});
```

Comment: Can someone please clarify why this is the "best" way and not using the firebase admin SDK?

Comment: @RukshanJS Unfortunately, it's been a while and I couldn't find the file in my computer to help you. Sorry!

Answer (score 3):

When a new Promise is created it will execute automatically. The resolve and reject functions you passed in the executor will change the state of promise to resolved or rejected respectively when called. Have a look at [this link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise)

The .then and .catch implementations will execute for the resolved and rejected promise. So your code looks fine as far as execution of promise is concerned.

Depends if the control is coming to the block you've written. As i can see **res.send** in your implementation it must be inside some (req,res) middleware.

So check if the execution is coming to the that middleware.

Comment: Thank you, Rahul. I rewrote the function call verifyTokenId without the callback and managed to make it work. I embedded the whole thing in an async function which returns a promise at the end instead.